# Remove HTML tag attribute in slim when attribute should not be displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

I would like to remove class attribute when class should not be displayed  in Slim.

In ERB, I could use:

```
<input <%= "class='foo'" if false %> />
<input />
```

How do I do this in Slim?

I found this, but I feel there must be a more idiomatic solution:

```
| <input "#{'class=\"foo\"' if false}" />
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the value of an attribute is `nil`, then the entire attribute will be omitted (actually this is happens for `nil` or `false` for most cases, but it looks like the `class` attribute behaves differently for `false` and `true`):

```slim
input class=('foo' if condition)
```

This will output

```html
<input class="foo" />
```

if `condition` is `true`, and

```html
<input />
```

if `condition` is false.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the splat (*) operator to help define conditional attributes for tags in slim, using hashes containing the attributes to be added.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Splat_attributes__

The splat operator will expand a hash into a set of attributes to be added to the tag.  If the hash is empty, no attributes will be added.

For example,

```
- admin_classes = @User.admin? ? {class: "foo"} : {}
input *admin_classes
```

if @User.admin? == true, it should render

```
<input class="foo">
```

else if @User.admin? == false, it should render

```
<input>
```

For attributes like "class" or other attributes that have attribute merging turned on, you can also do something like this:

```
- admin_classes = @User.admin? ? {class: ["foo","bar"]} : {}
input *admin_classes class="biz"
```

if @User.admin? == true, it should render

```
<input class="foo bar biz">
```

else if @User.admin? == false, it should render

```
<input class="biz">
```